# How to access Data in multipleviewControllers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I will try to explain the scenario as best as I can. 
Lets say if viewControllerA tells the model to hold some data(for example data from a json response) and then viewControllerD(or any other viewcontroller) needs the data, how do i access the data from the model. Creating an instance of the model in viewControllerD creates a fresh instance without any data.

Below code explains the scenario.

ViewControllerA

let userdetails = UserDetails(json: self.userDetailsList!)

userdetailsarray.append(userdetails) //a global array

//Model
class UserDetails: NSObject {

```
var name : String?
var profession : String?
var id: String?
init(json: NSDictionary) {

    let name = json["name"] as? String
    let profession = json["profession"] as? String
    let id = json["id"] as? String

    self.name = name
    self.profession = profession
    self.id = id
    super.init()
}
```

}
Possible Solution I know: Creating a global variable

var userdetailsarray = [UserDetails]

and appending UserDetails(model) into this array and using this array across multiple viewControllers. An alternative solution could be the model class being singleton.
I am looking for a more optimistic solution. Thankyou

Comment: I think this question can be replied in many different ways... I'd prefer dependency injection, but there are a lot of other ways.

Comment: @Luca D'Alberti. It would be helpful to know how can i achieve this using dependency injection.

Comment: When you make ViewControllerD either init it or pass it along the user ...

Comment: have you tried using a singleton for the data?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is more make it encrypted using **NSKeyedArchiever** and store it in user defaults. Whenever you required the data you can fetch it from user defaults and un archive it using **NSKyedUnarchiever**.

**Note:** This is the best solution only if you want to persist the data.

Comment: A more general case solution is, "persist the data in a way that accessible from any part of your application, via some centralized access point." Whether that persistence mechanism is NSKeyedArchiver, CoreData, raw SQLite, User Defaults, text files, or a server call is irrelevant to your callers. It may even be the case that the data is relatively small, and doesn't need to persist across app invocations, in which case an in-memory store is sufficient.